# Where to place Finally with try catch block in java

Tags: java

i'm test a web application by finding element with webdriver and i want to know if the first element is not found then i want continue executing the second code, so i placed a finally but with my code, even after placeing finally, the code stops to execute and did not continue the second step.

Please any help, thank you
Here is my code:

```
// ---First Step-----------------------------------------
try {
    driver.findElement(By.className("label")).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println(" label is displayed");
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("label is not displayed");
} finally {
    System.out.println("Go to the next step");
}

driver.findElement(By.className("label")).click();

Thread.sleep(3000);

// ---Second Step------------------------------------------
try {
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Resumé")).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println("Resumé is displayed");
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("Resumé is not displayed");
} finally {
    System.out.println("Go to the next step");
}

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Resumé")).click();
```

Comment: can you please include the output from your program, so we can see how far along it got?

Comment: For example if the program did not find the webelement "label", it should display the message "label is not displayed" and it will continue to execute the second step.

Comment: ok, but what did it actually display when you ran it? did it display "label is not displayed?" was that all it displayed? if not, what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In First step Click on Label only when element is present. Click action was outside of the try catch block. So moved both click action in try

```
try {
    driver.findElement(By.className("label")).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println(" label is displayed");
    driver.findElement(By.className("label")).click();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("label is not displayed");
} **finally {
    System.out.println("Go to the next step");
}**

Thread.sleep(3000);

//---Second Step------------------------------------------      
try {
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Resumé")).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println("Resumé is displayed");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Resumé")).click();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("Resumé is not displayed");
} **finally {
    System.out.println("Go to the next step");
}**
```